# Permission denied,Python , CGI ,Apache

Tags: python, apache, raspberry-pi, cgi

Hi I am trying to run this python code in my /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mcp3008.py
I am working with a raspberry PI and an Apache server. I am pretty new to this, 
Thank you

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
#--------------------------------------
# This script reads data from a
# MCP3008 ADC device using the SPI bus.
#
# Author : Matt Hawkins
# Date   : 13/10/2013
#
# http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/
#
#--------------------------------------

import spidev
import time
import os

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<bold>Light:</bold>"
# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

# Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
# Channel must be an integer 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

# Function to convert data to voltage level,
# rounded to specified number of decimal places.
def ConvertVolts(data,places):
  volts = (data * 3.3) / float(1023)
  volts = round(volts,places)
  return volts

# Function to calculate temperature from
# TMP36 data, rounded to specified
# number of decimal places.
# TMP36 data, rounded to specified
# number of decimal places.
def ConvertTemp(data,places):

  # ADC Value
  # (approx)  Temp  Volts
  #    0      -50    0.00
  #   78      -25    0.25
  #  155        0    0.50
  #  233       25    0.75
  #  310       50    1.00
  #  388       75    1.25
  #  465      100    1.50
  #  543      125    1.75
  #  620      150    2.00
  #  698      175    2.25
  #  775      200    2.50
  #  853      225    2.75
  #  930      250    3.00
  # 1008      275    3.25
  # 1023      280    3.30

  temp = ((data * 330)/float(1023))-50
  temp = round(temp,places)
  return temp

# Define sensor channels
light_channel = 0
temp_channel  = 1

# Define delay between readings
delay = 5

while True:

  # Read the light sensor data
  light_level = ReadChannel(light_channel)
  light_volts = ConvertVolts(light_level,2)
 light_volts = ConvertVolts(light_level,2)

  # Read the temperature sensor data
  temp_level = ReadChannel(temp_channel)
  temp_volts = ConvertVolts(temp_level,2)
  temp       = ConvertTemp(temp_level,2)

  # Print out results
  print "------The 'Ponics Project--------------------------------------"
  print("Light : {} ({}V)".format(light_level,light_volts))
  print("Temperature in the room  is: {} ({}V) {} deg F".format(temp_level,temp_volts,(temp * 9/5)+ 32))
  # Wait before repeating loop
  time.sleep(delay)
```

The problem is that I get an error. 
This is what my var/log/apache2/error.log looks like

```
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:37 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:37 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1]   File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mcp3008.py", line 21, in <module>
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:37 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1]
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:37 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1] spi.open(0,0)
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:37 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[Wed Apr 29 21:15:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.2$
```

Comment: Have you run the script with sudo (i.e. sudo python <scriptname.py>)

Comment: Yes I have, I tried sudo adduser www-data spi
but the group SPI does not exist.

Comment: @frafrichile, Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To allow your web programs running on the Apache web server to talk to the SPI devices, you’ll need to give the user account that runs the Apache web server permissions for the SPI devices. Enter this command:

sudo usermod -a -G spi www-data

You need to reboot the PI before changes take effect